# bison calculator problem

Tags: bison

```
stmt : expr  {printf("%d\n",$1);}
      ;

expr :  expr '+' expr  {$$ = $1 + $3;}
     |  expr '-' expr  {$$ = $1 - $3;}
     |  INTEGER        {$$ = $1;}
     ;
```

When is the stmt non terminal being executed by bison. When it sees which character ?

Comment: I don't get the question. What's `stmp`?

Comment: oops it was a typo. now i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, these are all the rules from your bison input, the nonterminal symbol `stmt` gets "executed" as soon as `EOF` is reached (i.e.: no further input and the last `expr` has been reduced).

However, there are conflicts in your grammar.